# Node.js returning user in callback and passing to page render

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am struggling to understand how to get the user object returned and posted to the req.user when the page renders.

This is for a password reset page, user enters an email, a reset link with a token is sent via email and the token+expiration date entered into the table. When user clicks the link -

In my Routes I have :

```
router.get('/:token',resetpwd, getReset);
```

Then when resetpwd is returned then getReset handles my rendering and passing of data via the following code

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
var content = {
    title: 'password reset | title',
    user: req.user,
    customCSS: [],
    customJS: []
    //message:req.flash()
};

 res.render('reset', content);
```

the resetpwd has the following code

```
var User = require('../models').user;
var flash = require('connect-flash');

module.exports = function(req, done) {
User.findAll({
    where: {
        resetPasswordToken: req.params.token,
        resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() } //$gt = greater than
    }
}).then(function(user) {

    console.log(user[0]);

    if (user[0] === undefined) {
        console.log('No User found , redirecting to forgot page');
        req.flash('error', 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired.');
        return res.redirect('/forgot');
    }
    console.log('found user, return callback')
    return done(null, user[0]);


}, function(err) {
    console.log('error here?');
    // return done(err, null);
    //error handle this
});

};
```

It is correctly redirecting when the password code is invalid or has expired. When all is valid it gives an error "done is not a function" or if I rewrite it without using done (as below) it hangs  at the console log but no error ).

```
module.exports = function(req, res) {

//-same as previous-

    console.log('found user, return it')
    return (null, user[0]);

//same as previous

};
```

what is the correct way of returning the req.user and passing into my getReset.
NOTE: I have used FindAll and user array due to having to use mssql and sequelize, with FindOne or offset not working on mssql2008.

Answer (score 0):

@Ray_Hack i am suppose here that 3 parameter for this function, i think you miss res parameter, and where you get it please also check there

```
var User = require('../models').user;    
var flash = require('connect-flash');

module.exports = function(req,res,done) {
User.findAll({
    where: {
        resetPasswordToken: req.params.token,
        resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() } //$gt = greater than
    }
}).then(function(user) {

    console.log(user[0]);

    if (user[0] === undefined) {
        console.log('No User found , redirecting to forgot page');
       req.flash('error', 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired.');  
        return res.redirect('/forgot');
    } 
               console.log('found user, return callback')
               return done(null, user[0]);


}, function(err) {
    console.log('error here?');
    // return done(err, null);
    //error handle this
});

};
```

Comment: just added the 3rd parameter of Done. Tried using Next instead also and I can get it to work if I manually assign req.user = user[0] before the function does a return next() at the end. But that obvious is not the right way?. thanks